# Email already taken error on mongoid while using rspec

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I am using RSpec, Mongoid DB and FactoryGirl. Following is my **lesson_spec.rb** and **factories/users.rb**.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Lesson do
  context "has valid data" do
    before :each do
      @course_template = FactoryGirl.create(:course_template1)
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
      @course_template.share_with(@user)
      @lesson = FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)
      @course_template.add_lesson(@lesson)
      @course_instance = FactoryGirl.create(:course_instance)
      @course_template.add_course_instance(@course_instance)
    end

    it "has course instances" do
      p @lessons
      @lessons.should respond_to :course_templates
    end

  end
end
```

## factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_lesson, class: User do
    first_name 'Lesson'
    last_name 'User'
    roles ["teacher"]
    email "teacher2@example.com"
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'
  end
end
```

I am getting following failure while running following rspec command 2nd time onwards:

bundle exec rspec spec/models/lesson_spec.rb

```
1) Lesson has valid data has course instances
     Failure/Error: @course_template.share_with(@user)
     Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:

       Problem:
         Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 51f9fb3479478f6fcb000002.
       Summary:
         When calling User.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 51f9fb3479478f6fcb000002 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 51f9fb3479478f6fcb000002.
       Resolution:
         Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
     # ./lib/shared.rb:29:in `share_new_asset_with'
     # ./lib/shared.rb:51:in `update_or_share_with'
     # ./lib/shared.rb:57:in `share_with'
     # ./spec/models/lesson_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my own question in better way.
I am using [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) for cleaning up test data.

Referring to [Avdi Grimm's blog](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/), I am writing here for MongoDB ORM.

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

This will disable rspec-rails’ implicit wrapping of tests in a database transaction.

```
#spec/support/database_cleaner.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

These steps help to cleanup the test data before specs run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sequences to generate unique emails:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequences-and-associations

Replace your

```
email "teacher2@example.com"
```

with

```
sequence(:email) { |n| "teacher#{ n }@example.com }
```

Comment: Still getting same error. It doesn't creating unique email ids. Any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid can't find the `User` with the following id `51f9fb3479478f6fcb000002` since you created using `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` in your spec (not saved in database).

2 solutions here:

- Create a user using `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` (slow, needs to write in db but sometimes necessary)
- Stub the `User.find` action to return your built user

  User.stub(:find).and_return(@user)

Also, prefer `let` syntax over setting instance variables in a `before` block:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

before do
  # ...
end
```

Regarding the issue you describe, try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :email do |n|
    "foo#{n}@bar.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I got more better approach and writing here.